# Fancytree doesn't collapse nodes that have expanded key set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I have the following JSON tree structure:

```
[
    {
        "expanded":"false",
        "key":"_23",
        "title":"Politics",
        "data":{
            "id":"23",
            "name_en":"Politics",
            "description_en":"",
            "seo_title_en":"",
            "seo_description_en":"",
            "name_sr":"Politika",
            "description_sr":"",
            "seo_title_sr":"",
            "seo_description_sr":"",
            "slug_en":"politics",
            "slug_sr":"politika"
        },
        "children":[
            {
                "key":"_24",
                "title":"Domestic politics",
                "data":{
                    "id":"24",
                    "name_en":"Domestic politics",
                    "description_en":"",
                    "seo_title_en":"",
                    "seo_description_en":"",
                    "name_sr":"Doma\u0107a politika",
                    "description_sr":"",
                    "seo_title_sr":"",
                    "seo_description_sr":"",
                    "slug_en":"domestic-politics",
                    "slug_sr":"domaca-politika"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "expanded":"false",
        "key":"_21",
        "title":"Sport",
        "data":{
            "id":"21",
            "name_en":"Sport",
            "description_en":"",
            "seo_title_en":"",
            "seo_description_en":"",
            "name_sr":"Sport",
            "description_sr":"",
            "seo_title_sr":"",
            "seo_description_sr":"",
            "slug_en":"sport",
            "slug_sr":"sport"
        },
        "children":[
            {
                "key":"_22",
                "title":"Football",
                "data":{
                    "id":"22",
                    "name_en":"Football",
                    "description_en":"",
                    "seo_title_en":"",
                    "seo_description_en":"",
                    "name_sr":"Fudbla",
                    "description_sr":"",
                    "seo_title_sr":"",
                    "seo_description_sr":"",
                    "slug_en":"football",
                    "slug_sr":"fudbla"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you see the two nodes at first level have expanded set to false. But those aren't shown collapsed in tree.

I load tree from AJAX request. Here is the init code:

```
$("#news-categories-table").fancytree({
    icon: false,
    checkbox: false,
    titlesTabbable: true,
    source: {
        url: SITE_URL + "news_categories/get_tree",
        cache: false
    },
    extensions: ["table", "dnd"],
    table: {
        nodeColumnIdx: 1   // render node expander, icon, and title to this column (default: #0)
    },
    dnd: {
        autoExpandMS: 400,
        draggable: { // modify default jQuery draggable options
            zIndex: 1000,
            scroll: false,
            containment: "parent",
            revert: "invalid"
        },
        preventRecursiveMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes on own descendants
        preventVoidMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes 'before self', etc.
        dragStart: function(node, data) {
            return true;
        },
        dragEnter: function(node, data) {
            return true;
        },
        dragExpand: function(node, data) {
            return true;
        },
        dragOver: function(node, data) {
            return true;
        },
        dragLeave: function(node, data) {
            return true;
        },
        dragStop: function(node, data) {
            return true;
        },
        dragDrop: function(node, data) {
            data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
        }
    },
    renderColumns: function(event, data) {
        var node = data.node,
            $tdList = $(node.tr).find(">td");

        // td 1 value is edit icon
        $tdList.eq(0).html(node.data.id);
    }
});
```

Can this be solved somehow? I used fancytree before, older versions this was not problem. Expanded false nodes, were collapsed upon loading tree.

Here is the screenshot also.

[image: Tree screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expanded option requires a boolean value. Try passing

```
"expanded": false,
```

instead of

```
"expanded": "false",
```

Comment: That structure is saved from this method(s) of fancytree api. Like this.

`var tree = $("#news-categories-table").fancytree("getTree").toDict(false)`. Is that wrong?

Comment: I found error. I didn't JSON stringify tree structure to send it to server as JSON string but array. So when i did JSON encode on server it messed up file types. Anyway now it is OK. Thank you. :)